# Add PropertyChangeListener to to multiple JComboBoxes

Tags: java, jcombobox, propertychangelistener

i have a Table with `JComboBoxes` and want to add a`PropertyChangeListener` to every single `JComboBox`, because some selections of ComboBoxes have to change the selectables of other `JComboBoxes`.

I can't add all those listeners manually because there are very much of them.

I'm initializing the ComboBoxes with an array, so i already tried to add the listener when I create the `JComboBox` like this:

```
comboBox[i].addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
```

But it didnt work because the field variable `i` is not final and I need this variable.

How can I store this variable in the comboBox or is there a other possibility to solve this Problem?

Comment: `ActionListener` != `PropertyChangeListener`. Please rephrase your question, and add some clarity.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: Because I already edited it thank you mre for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can create all those comboboxes, then you can also add 'all those listeners' manually. There are several options:

- You create a new listener each time you create a new combobox, and pass that index `i` to that listener (either by anonymous class, inner class, or fully fledged class) or by making a final copy as Francis Upton suggested in his answer
- If you need that `i` only to retrieve the combobox from which the event originated, you can also call `event#getSource` (which is available on both the `ActionEvent` as well as on the `PropertyChangeEvent` since your question is not clear about the type of listener). In this case you can either create the listener only once, or create one listener for each combobox

Comment: But how can I pass that index, i created a own class which extends `JComboBox` and added the index, but because I don't know the index, i cant get the index, that wasn't very smart by me^^.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You say you have added the index (to the listener or the combobox ?). Since you have access to the combobox from the listener through the `getSource` method of the event, you can access the index if its stored in the combobox. If its stored in the listener, then there is no problem at all accessing it from the listener

Comment: I added the index to the constructor of my `JComboBox`.

Comment: Well then, in your listener you can do `int id = ((MyCheckBoxExtension)aPropertyChangeEvent.getSource()).getID();` or something similar to access that ID

Answer (score 0):

You can extend JComboBox and init what you want in constructor

Comment: I don't see how that fits with the requirement. They want to use the same listener for all of the controls.

Comment: @FrancisUpton: Based on the sample code, the OP is making a new instance for the for each combobox.

Comment: Its everytime the same listener, just the variable has to be different

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you can copy i to another final variable, and refer to that final variable in your `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an anonymous class, make a real class that implements the interface you care about. That way you can pass the combobox index (or even the combobox instance if that is all you need).